# How to calculate time interval between two "keyup" events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, time

i need to create some kind of elementary pos with javascript. I have an barcode scanner that work like a keyboard. So i want to automaticaly detect when the input come from the barcode and then create a report with that codes. I think an good idea is to calculate the difference of typing speed because the scanner is really fast:

```
if there a dalay between keyup > 300ms = another scan

var speed = new Date().getTime() - lastkey;
    lastkey = (new Date()).getTime();
        console.log(speed);
    if(speed > 300) {
        //little delay for prevent computer overhead o_O
        var create_d = setTimeout(createchange,300)
        } else {
        //barcode sanning continue
        clearTimeout(create_d)
    }
```

## [JsFiddle link <](http://jsfiddle.net/StartStep/sbWH9/12/)

Comment: Please provide the JSFiddle code in your question. Links can break in the future.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @charlietfl ,hi ,He already wrote question above

Comment: @Pratik: no, he didn't. He made a series of statements.

Comment: JsFiddle have all the code that you need (.-.)

Comment: I posted some code, is it ok?

Comment: What's to stop the user scanning the same barcode twice? 300ms isn't very long.

Comment: Do you have other propouses SlitCanvas?

Comment: @Kharchi the demo is good, but a proper explanation of the problem is very important. This is a question and answer site

Comment: When scanning the barcode work like an keyboard and write text at very hight speed rate. That speed rate may be decreased by computer speed or browser so i set some kind of delay at 300ms. Why i need to check if barcode entering is stopped? Becouse i would like to reduce user interaction. If 300ms passed and no other input it's mean = barcode typing end. So i clear the input and prepare input field for another scan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using pure JS:

```
document.body.onkeydown = function ()
{
 var time = this._time;
 var timestamp = new Date().getTime();
 if (time)
  console.log(timestamp - time);

 this._time = timestamp;
}
```

The console will display difference between keydown events (in ms)

Comment: one thing how exactly "this._time" work? never seen before ^^

Comment: `this` represents `document.body` in the context of the function. `_time` is just a variable set upon the object. It could be as well be `counter`, `abc` or anything else